# What is the correct way of using the use and this keyword in java?

Tags: java

So I'm extending the Java Rectangle class. And I happen to be a bit confused with the use of `this` and `super` and when each should be used. I understand that `super` is the super class (parent class) and `this` is the current class you're calling it from.

I currently have a `BetterRectangle` class extending from the `Rectangle` class and a method:

```
boolean isCongruent(Rectangle r)
{
    if(r.width == super.width && r.height == super.height)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Does it matter if I use `this.width` and `this.height` instead of `super`? 
Which would be the more correct way of using regardless both give me the same answer?

Comment: as long as `width` and `height` are not declared in this class (overidden/shadowed) then `this.width` or even `width` would IMO be more readable

Comment: I can't see your entire class (or superclass), but `super.width` seems to imply that the `width` field is actually _public_ in your superclass.  If so, this is probably bad design, and instead you should be using the getters for the `width` field.  If, on the other hand, you defined `width` in the above class, then you may use either `width` or `this.width`.

Comment: The superclass is java's own Rectangle class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html

Comment: The fact that you are confused indicates that the use of `super.height` is not ideal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it matter if I use this.width and this.height instead of super?

If your subclass has inherited the attributes from its superclass (in this case, Rectangle's `width` and `height`), then your subclass now owns `width` and `height` as its own attributes.

So if your intention is to access the subclass' attributes, using `this` (which refers to the class itself) will make more sense isn't it? So I will go with using `this`.

**Attributes inherited to child**:

```
class Parent{  
    protected int width = 5;
    protected int height = 5;
}

class Child extends Parent{

    public Child(int width, int height){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height; 
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return this.height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return this.width;
    }

    public int getSuperHeight() {
        return super.height;
    }

    public int getSuperWidth() {
        return super.width;
    } 
}
```

**Test Run**:

```
Child c = new Child(2, 3);
System.out.println(c.getWidth() + " " + c.getHeight());             //2 3
System.out.println(c.getSuperWidth() + " " + c.getSuperHeight());   //2 3
```

---

Like what ScarryWombat mentioned, if the attributes are masked by the attributes declared in the subclass, then using `this` and `super` makes a difference. `this` now refers to the attributes declared within the subclass instead of the inherited attributes.

**Attributes inherited to child, but masked**:

```
class Child extends Parent{

    private int width;
    private int height;

    public Child(int width, int height){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height; 
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return this.height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return this.width;
    }

    public int getSuperHeight() {
        return super.height;
    }

    public int getSuperWidth() {
        return super.width;
    }    
}
```

**Test Run**:

```
Child c = new Child(2, 3);
System.out.println(c.getWidth() + " " + c.getHeight());             //2 3
System.out.println(c.getSuperWidth() + " " + c.getSuperHeight());   //5 5
```

Answer (score 1):

If your subclass has field `width` (and `height`), then `super.width`'s value can be different than `this.width` depending on how you initialize the fields. Here is a quick test:-

```
import java.awt.*;

public class BetterRectangle extends Rectangle {

    public int width;

    void testWidth() {
        System.out.println("width = " + width);
        System.out.println("this.width = " + this.width);
        System.out.println("super.width = " + super.width);
    }
}
```

--

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rectangle rect = new BetterRectangle();
    rect.width = 10; //sets the value of super class's field
    ((BetterRectangle) rect).width = 90; //sets the value of subclass's field

    ((BetterRectangle) rect).testWidth();
}
```

This prints:-

```
width = 90
this.width = 90
super.width = 10
```

Note that `width` and `this.width` prints the same thing because of **data hiding**. You'll have to add the super keyword to access the super class's field.

If you don't have a `width` variable in your subclass, then `super.width` and `this.width` point to the same field, so why not just use `width`?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there should hardly ever be a genuine need to use either this. or super.

Looking at your iscongruent() method, ask yourself how it could ever return false.  Answer : that's only possible if the super class and the sub class both have a member of the same name, that is, there are multiple distinc fields named 'width' and/or 'height'.  That's bad practice.

Why is that so ?  Suppose these fields are supposed to carry the same semantics.  At all time.  So then why are there two distinct appearances of the field ?  It's plain redundancy and that's a source of bugs.  Eliminate one of the two and you're out of the problem.  Suppose contrariwise that these fields can possibly carry different semantics.  You likely want to expose those semantics in your sub class at least through a getter (and perhaps a setter too).  So now you have getters (and perhaps setters) in both your super and sub classes with ***identical*** signatures but ***differing*** semantics.  That's plain anti-design-by-contract.  Sub classes should never alter the semantics of methods established by their super class.  And finally, if you don't want to expose the same-named field in the sub class, there's nothing to stop you from just naming it 'localWidth' or 'subWidth' or whatever other name that ***provides a better and more detailed explanation of the intended semantics***.

That said, here are some cases where using 'this' and/or 'super' is warranted or even unavoidable :

In constructors, when setting fields from the value of a parameter that has been given the same name as the field :

```
this.x = x;  /* x = x would mean an assignment to the method parameter, not the field */
```

In overriding implementations, when you also need to execute the code as defined in the super class :

```
method ( ... ) {
  super.method( ... );
  /* some extra code here to deal with the extra state in the sub class */
}
```

There may be more, but in general abundant use of 'this' and 'super' leads to too much 'noise' that ***can*** be avoided without harming readability.  Of course that's just a matter of opinion and of preferred style.

Answer (score -1):

The best way may be is to look at how standard Java classes accesses the variables. `javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret` extends `Rectangle`. Except where there are local variable clashes - the access of variables do not use any `this` or `super` specifiers. I would stick to that :).

For example, this is the `repaint` method:

```
protected final synchronized void repaint() {
    if (component != null) {
        component.repaint(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```